# OOP concepts to model a certain setting?

Tags: java, oop, uml

I am working on a problem where i have to model a situation of a retail shop which sells books,audio CDs and DvDs with oop concepts.I have to describe the common characteristics and draw a uml diagram to represent the relations.I am a beginner in Java and i am having troubles with modelling such situations.

```
You work as a programmer for a retail company selling cultural and 
electronic products. You are instructed to design the object model for 
handling the stock items before it can be programmed.

The company sells books, DVDs and audio CDs. A title, a price and the number of items in
the store stock characterize all these retail items. These items also have specialized 
characteristics: a book has a number of pages; a DVD has a running time and an audio CD has 
a number of tracks etc.

1)What OOP concept would you use to represent the common characteristics of books, DVDs
and audio CDs?
2)What other OOP concept would you use to ensure that common functionalities (retrieve
the price of an item and retrieve the quantity of an item) would be implemented?
3)Draw a UML diagram to represent your object model.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1) Inheritance/Polymorphism: Introduce an Abstract Class Item, the different Items then can extend the class Item and by doing that, sharing the Items properties.
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp

2) Create an Interface Sellable, make the Class Item implement the Sellable Interface, so every Item has to implement those Methods.
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp

3) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_class_diagram.htm